# How to add Kotlin PSI source files to IDEA Plugin project configuration

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin, intellij-plugin

I am trying to add support for kotlin for one of the IDEA plugins.

So far, I found this [page](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000724850-Make-Intellij-Idea-plugin-work-with-Kotlin-files) and understood that I need to work with kotlin PSI files, such as `KtClass` and others.

When I was setting up my project I added idea source files to sdk(by cloning this [repo](http://git.jetbrains.org/idea/community.git)), to make it easier to debug + see documentation.

However it seems that these idea source files doesn't include kotlin source files, such as mentioned `KtClass` and others, which I use in my project. Currently I see only decompiled version of these files.

Is there any way to add them like with other IDEA source files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those source files belongs to the Kotlin plugin, which is not strictly a part of IntelliJ IDEA distribution. You need to add the Kotlin plugin source to the project as well as the IDEA source.

There're two modules needed:

- https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/tree/master/idea
- https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/tree/master/compiler/psi/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin

Comment: thank for your answer. I added sources you mention, and indeed I can see there now `KtClass` source file in idea, but somehow IDEA doesn't map `KtClass`which I am using in my code to this source files, so using search in project I can see poth `.class`and `.kt` files, but when I am clicking on class I am using/or debugging I still just see decompiled version.

Comment: Have you tried adding the source as a library of all your modules?

Comment: not sure what do you mean? Currently in setting I have specified Intllij SDK, where I added `kotlin-plugin` to `classpath` and sources from your links to `sourcepaths`

Comment: If you're using gradle, this is incorrect. You need to create a `library` and add all sources into it and add the `library` as a dependency of the `module`s. All operations can be done in the Project Structure dialog