# How to set up Kotlin PSI for IntelliJ IDEA Gradle Plugin?

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm building a Plugin for the IntelliJ IDE to manipulate Kotlin files in a project. I've been able to write a bunch of tests to take a Kotlin file and generate a new file based on its contents. When I run this plugin in the IDE I'm unable to detect files as Kotlin files. When looking at the debugger my file says that it is a KtFile from the `org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi` library. But if I try to cast it to a KtFile I get an error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtFile cannot be cast to org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtFile
```

So apparently the library version is off between runtime and compile time. What do I have to do to configure my plugin to use the correct Kotlin PSI at plugin runtime?

My `plugin.xml` looks like this:

```
<idea-plugin>
    <id>...</id>
    <name>...</name>
    <vendor email="..." url="...">...</vendor>

    <description><...</description>

    <depends>com.intellij.modules.all</depends>
    <depends>org.jetbrains.kotlin</depends>

    <actions>...</actions>
</idea-plugin>
```

My `build.gradle.kts` looks like:

```
plugins {
    id("org.jetbrains.intellij") version "0.4.16"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.61"
}

group = "..."
version = "..."

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
    implementation(kotlin("compiler-embeddable", "1.3.61"))
    implementation(kotlin("gradle-plugin", "1.3.61"))

    testImplementation(group = "junit", name = "junit", version = "4.12")
}

buildscript {
    repositories { mavenCentral() }
    dependencies {
        classpath(kotlin("compiler-embeddable", "1.3.61"))
        classpath(kotlin("gradle-plugin", "1.3.61"))
    }
}

intellij {
    version = "2019.1.4"
    setPlugins("Kotlin")
}
tasks {
    compileKotlin {
        kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    compileTestKotlin {
        kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
tasks.getByName<org.jetbrains.intellij.tasks.PatchPluginXmlTask>("patchPluginXml") {
    changeNotes("...")
}
```

I already am aware of [How to include Kotlin PSI classes (e.g. KtClass) in Intellij IDEA Gradle plugin project written in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58803103/how-to-include-kotlin-psi-classes-e-g-ktclass-in-intellij-idea-gradle-plugin) and [How to add Kotlin PSI source files to IDEA Plugin project configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50183198/how-to-add-kotlin-psi-source-files-to-idea-plugin-project-configuration) which is essentially what I want to be answered but haven't gotten anything to fix my issue. Maybe there is some documentation on this issue but it evades my searches.

Answer (score 0):

Your `dependencies` should include `implementation(kotlin("reflect"))` and `plugin.xml` should include `<depends>org.jetbrains.kotlin</depends>`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
It was solved by adding

```
 plugins.set(listOf("Kotlin"))
```

at the intelllij section at gradle